# Can we move Google Analytics data to other account?

Tags: import, google-analytics, export, data-transfer

Started a webpage that now contains a lot of analytic data.  Now that I have the client **GA Tracking ID** I would like to move the data I already have to that account.

> **Is this possible?**

I get the Google Analytics API, I can always fetch all the data I want, but my problem is, upon I have the data how can I send / push this data to other account

in other words, **How can I transfer** data?

The domain is the same, only the account Id in use was a different one (my own, instead of the client's)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[It is not possible](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72271):

> You cannot currently transfer profiles or account data from one account to another account.

Google Analytics does not provide any flexibility with importing, exporting, or modifying any past data. Any data you have in one account cannot be moved to another.

With GA, the only way to get data in to an account is directly via `__utm.gif` requests, usually through their JavaScript snippet, but that doesn't allow for any way to import past data, since the date is fixed according to when the data is sent in.

Further, the Google Analytics API is read-only, and doesn't provide any way to import or move data.

(This answer is slightly less true for [Universal Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en)

Comment: dang! ... I was really hoping for a solution.

Comment: @balexandre If this is mission-critical, the one potential solution would be looking into purchasing an Urchin license, which is basically like installing a less-advanced, but more flexible, version of Google Analytics that should allow you to do things like data reprocessing.

Comment: at US$9995 it's a little out of reach, but thank you for the solution, I had no idea we could host our own Analytic Center!

Comment: There's actually a petition for this feature! http://www.petitiononline.com/analyse1/petition.html

Answer (score 3):

http://piwik.org/ is a good alternative, open source analytics system, not unlike Google Analytics, but without some of the constraints like this.

Answer (score 3):

I think now it's possible to move data from one account to another.
Check out this article:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6370521?hl=en

> If you need to reorganize your properties in Analytics, you can move them (and their views) from one account to another.
>   Moving properties lets you keep your Analytics implementation current with your business. You might be reorganizing after a merger, after an internal restructuring, after hiring a new agency, or you might be developing a new Roll-Up strategy.

Answer (score 2):

This was not possible in 2011 when the question was originally asked. Google added this capability to GA in 2016 ([source](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2016/09/improved-analytics-administration-via.html)). In addition to Google's documentation which [engray provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278914/can-we-move-google-analytics-data-to-other-account/47829352#47829352), there are several blog posts which discuss how.

- [How to transfer a Google Analytics property from one Google Account to another](https://blog.sparksuite.com/how-to-transfer-a-google-analytics-property-from-one-google-account-to-another-57129ca5d05b)
- [How to Move a Property to Another Account in Google Analytics](https://carloseo.com/move-properties-google-analytics/)

How to move a property:

1. Sign in to Google Analytics & navigate to Admin section.
2. In the ACCOUNT column choose the account that contains the property you want to move.
3. In the PROPERTY column, select the property you want to move.
4. Click Property Settings, then click Move property.
5. Select the destination account.
6. Choose your permissions settings.
7. Click Move.
8. Confirm data processing, then click Save.

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible to do this as i was curious and found a few forum posts mentioning it:

Log into GA.
Goto the Account List.
Find your web property, you can't click the 'property' itself but a profile under it...
Then click on Admin on top-right side.
Go 'Up' a Level. 
For example the breadcrumb says:
'Account list' › 'FOO (www.foo.com)' › 'FOO (www.foo.com) - (Default Profile)'
and now the breadcrumb should say when you click 2nd breadcrumb link:
'Account list' › 'FOO (www.foo.com)'

Now you have an option to add other users to this whole web property by going to the Users tab.
Add an Administrator user to this specific property. You can setup this user for them on gmail that they can change the password later after you set it up (or use their Google Account email they provide and maybe walk through with them to make sure they do it correctly).

Then login as that user, and delete the old user. Then that *should* 'transfer' to a new account.

Comment: No, that doesn't do what the original question asked for. That just changes around the users, not move the profile into a different account.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this situation - export all data from Google account and import it into Tableau or QlickView. And use desktop analysis. In any case these data will be actual no more than 2 years.